# How to inject values from Java Class to Datasource Bean in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-jdbc, applicationcontext

This might sound like a novice question. I want to inject datasource properties (which I am getting at runtime) and inject it to the bean..

I have a method in my javaclass...

```
public <String,String>map myMethod(Map<String, String> model) {

        Map mapA = new HashMap();
        mapA.put("username", "element 1");
        mapA.put("password", "element 2");
        mapA.put("host", "element 3");

        return map;
    }
```

I want to inject these values to my datasource bean in application-context.xml

```
   <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value=""/> // inject values here
        <property name="url" />
        <property name="username" />
        <property name="password" />
    </bean>
```

I have seen numerous example on injecting values to beans using properties file but I could not figure out on how to inject a value from java class to the bean properties.

Thanks

Comment: Is Spring Boot an option? It'll do this for you out of the box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a `@Configuration` class with a method annotated with `@Bean` returning an instance of `org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource`.

```
@Configuration
public class DatasourceConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public BasicDataSource dataSource() {
        BasicDataSource ds = new BasicDataSource();
        ds.setDriverClassName(""); // you can call your code here 
        ds.setUrl(""); // to get these configuration values
        ds.setUsername("");
        ds.setPassword("");
        return ds;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be a not so elegant solution, but what about this approach?

You can try to return a `String` from your method.

```
@Configuration
public class DatasourceConfiguration2 {
    @Bean
    public String getDataSourceSetting() {
        Map<String, String> map = myMethod(model); //assuming that you are not able to edit the original method
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (Entry<String, String> e : map.entrySet()) {
            sb.append(e.getKey()).append('=').append(e.getValue()).append(';');
        }
    }
}
```

In your xml you can define the property like:

```xml
 <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="connectionProperties" value="dataSourceSetting"/> 
    </bean>
```

Based on [dbcp api](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/api-2.1.1/org/apache/commons/dbcp2/BasicDataSource.html#setConnectionProperties-java.lang.String-):

> The "user" and "password" properties will be added explicitly, so they do not need to be included here.

Checking the source code you can see if user and password are null a message like `log("DBCP DataSource configured without a 'username'");` will be printed. But the property will be available there.

Finally, in case of `url` property, there is no option, you need to set it up explicitly.